# Reading option values in select

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have select values as follows:

```
<select id="SelectBox" multiple="multiple">

            <% foreach (var item in Model.Name)
            { %>
                <option value="<%= item.Value %>"><%=item.Text%></option>
            <% } 
            %>

            </select>
```

I have a function in jquery that will have to read both the text and value. I need to have the values in array so that I can display them in a table with a column Id and another column text.  My problem is that I`m not able to retrieve each and every value separately.  I`m having the text in one line, test1test2test3.

```
function read() {
            $("#SelectBox").each(function() {
                var value = $(this).val();
                var text = $(this).text();
                alert(value);alert(text);

            });
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close. You need to iterate over the `<option>`s, not the `<select>` elements:

```
$("#SelectBox option").each(function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  var text = $(this).text();
  alert(value);
  alert(text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function read() {
            $("#SelectBox > option").each(function() {
                var value = $(this).val();
                var text = $(this).text();
                alert(value);alert(text);

            });
        }
```