# Setting the value in a select dropdown using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, select, nan

I am having trouble when trying to set a value in a select. I keep seeing NaN as my result (in some browsers - mainly android smartphone / tablet default browsers)

I am running a simply if statement and setting the value if the condition is true:

```
if (variable1 >= variable2)
{
    $('select[title="title"]').val(variable1);
}
```

Where a 'typeof' check on both variable1 and variable2 before the if statement show them both as numbers. Despite this the resulting value shown in select in the browser is NaN.

I've even tried wrapping the javascript Number() function around the variables like so:

```
if (Number(variable1) >= Number(variable2))
{
    $('select[title="myTitle"]').val(Number(variable1));
}
```

But I still get the same result!

Note: This works fine in desktop / laptop browsers and even Opera Mobile on my Samsung Galaxy S2 but as I'm working towards this being an app to run on any phone I wanted to be complete in my error checking.

edit:
In case it's my select thats the problem (as suggested below) what's wrong with it here?
Is it because it is converted to a string at the point I return it?

```
var startPoint = this.do_calcTotal(); // typeof startPoint shows as number
var endPoint = startPoint + 12; // typeof endPoint shows as number

var mySelect =   '<select title="myTitle" class="myClass">';

                    for (o=startPoint; o<endPoint; o++)
                    {
                        mySelect += '<option>'+Number(o)+'</option>'; // is this right?? it shows 'o' and 'Number(o)' as typeof number!?
                    }

mySelect += '</select></span></div>';

return mySelect;
```

Edit: and the code to add the current selected value to the span for display...

```
function do_changeNumberSpan(value)
{
    $('.mySpan').text(Number(value)); // even tried throwing a Number() round the value here!!
}
```

Comment: You said "the value shown" in the select box. Does that mean you see "NaN" as an option for your select box? That could mean the problem is with your option generation code.

Comment: Yes. Where it should be displaying a number it shows blank and the span where I show the value shows NaN. Good thinking though. I'll check the loop where I am building the options.

Comment: @InvisibleBacon OK Here's my select building loop. What have I got wrong here or is it just the fact that I'm returning it that it then becomes a string not a value?

Comment: You said "the span where I show the value shows NaN". Is there a span that you are copying the selected value to at some point? Can you show that code?

Comment: Added the code as an edit to the original post

Comment: Sorry, a little confused. So is the NaN being shown as the selected option in the select box? or are you copying the selected value to another element when it is changed?

Comment: Sorry. Select is a blank option and the value in the span is NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Check out this jsfiddle. This should help you understand a little bit of what your goal is... and how you can accomplish it. 
http://jsfiddle.net/aaronfrost/yFuyu/

Comment: Thanks Aaron. Have taken a couple of days off from this but after taking another look I think your example may have put me onto something. I have a question though. Your example is great for when I know the options before hand. But I am building the select drop-down each time so the index of each option will potentially be different each time. How would I check the contents of each option first to then know which option index to set as selected? (note: this is probably a stupid question with a very obvious answer but I am now too tired to know any better! Sorry.)

Comment: Actually..... I think this may work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513436/reading-option-values-in-select - thanks again

Comment: Sorted. If I set the option to selected rather than try to "force" the value - .val() - to be a specific number it doesn't error.